# Pass PHP Variables to Ajax and post them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How would I pass a `PHP` variable to `AJAX` I've tried using `var sStr = "<?php echo $game ?>.";` It will print it out ok but i cant get it to `POST` it to a `PHP` File. Here is my Code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$game=$_GET['id']; 
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("php.php",
    {
      game:"<?php echo $game; ?>",
      city:"Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Add to Favourites</button>
```

Comment: try with single quotes ``'<?php echo $game; ?>'``

Comment: So what is the actual problem?  Have you looked in network response to see whether your request to the server script it as expected?  Have you debugged within your `php.php` script to see if the problem is there?  What HTTP response code are you getting when trying to POST? Do you actually have a `button` element in your HTML? Right now, you haven't provided enough context to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't get it to post to a PHP file'? Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Can you see the data being moved about?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add a bit the code will just alert the whole script at the moment it should just post to the php file which will insert the variable into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the button by an ID and filter the quotes with `addslashes`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$game = $_GET['id'];
$game = addslashes($game);
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("php.php",
    {
      game:"<?=$game?>",
      city:"Duckburg"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button">Add to Favourites</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll give it a try in a Minute and let you know.

Comment: It has the same outcome